# Sync current active file with NPP folder as workspace tree view

Tags: notepad++

How I can sync the current open file in NPP with the tree view of Notepad++ Folder As Workspace?

When I use find in file (right-click on Folder As Workspace), then open the file from the matched item list, it will be hard to locate the actual file from the left panel of Folder As Workspace tree view.

Appreciate your help. Otherwise, please let me know how I can report this as a feature request.

Tarek